# Where and How I should put the plot title and legend in the following R Base Plot

Tags: r, pdf, plot

I have an R script that where I produce multiple (4 rows and 4 columns) histograms with density lines per page in a pdf output file using R Base Graphics.  The stripped down (to avoid clutter and resulting distraction) version of this program is shown below:

```
pdf("multiple.pdf", width = 17, height = 11)
par(mfrow = c(4,4),mar=c(1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5),oma=c(4,5,7,3))

#  Where should I put the Plot's title and Legend???

for (hra_color in df_hra_colors$hra) {
  l <- density(...) 
  p <- hist(...)

  # plot the first five tests for starters
  for (current_test_index in 1:5) {
    ...
    for (x in test_vector)  {
        points(...)

    }
  }
}

dev.off()
```

Trouble is:  I cannot display the plot title, legend and the composite left and right axes labels using mtext.  If I try to put the title, legend, and labels after exiting the outermost 'for' loop, it only shows up in the last histogram and does not position properly.

If I put it where I ask 'where should I put the Plot's title and legend??? as I show in the source code below, I get the following message:

Error in title(title, line = -0.4, outer = TRUE) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet

I just tried to put the following line of code where I have the commented question:

```
title(title,line=-0.4,outer=TRUE)
```

Any idea how to get around this problem?  There are a quite a few histograms that the program needs to show such that they run onto the next page.  This works fine, but the title, legend, and the Axes labels are a problem.  Based on the feedback, here is full script of my code which is quite small really:

```
setwd("~/sampling_ricardo")
df <- read.csv("main.csv")
df <- df[df$hra != -9999, ]
# read in the hra colors file
df_hra_colors <- read.csv('lookup.csv')
df_hra_colors$hex <- rgb(df_hra_colors$red, df_hra_colors$green, df_hra_colors$blue,
                         maxColorValue = 255, alpha = 200)
df_hra_colors <- df_hra_colors[df_hra_colors$hra %in% df$hra, c(1,5)]  # 1 = hra, 5 = hex
df$hra <- factor(df$hra, levels = df_hra_colors$hra)

reset <- function() {
  par(mfrow=c(1, 1), oma=rep(2, 4), mar=rep(0, 4), new=TRUE)
  plot(0:1, 0:1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", axes=FALSE)
}
pdf("multiple.pdf", width = 17, height = 11)
reset()
legend(x="top",legend = c("MRP","SSK","TXC","BZT","FT"),pch = c(15,7,6,16,17),cex=0.8,horiz = TRUE,box.col=NA,y.intersp = 0.7,inset = 0)
title(title,line=-0.4,outer=TRUE)
mtext("HRA PCA 1",side = 1,outer = TRUE,line = 0,font = 2)
mtext("FREQUENCY",side = 2,outer = TRUE,line = 0,font = 2)
par(mfrow = c(4,4),mar=c(1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5),oma=c(4,5,7,3))

current_component <- 'pc1'
title <- current_component
df_columns <- colnames(df)

# loop thru each hra color in the hra_colors dataframe and create one histogram for each color
for (hra_color in df_hra_colors$hra) {
  df_current_color <- df[df$hra == hra_color, ]
  if (nrow(df_current_color) == 1) {
    next
  }
  l <- density(df_current_color[ , current_component]) 
  p <- hist(df_current_color[ , current_component],
            main = hra_color,
            col.main = df_hra_colors$hex[df_hra_colors$hra == hra_color],
            xlab = NA, ylab = NA,
            ylim = c(0, max(l$y)), border = "black",
            col = df_hra_colors$hex[df_hra_colors$hra == hra_color],
            las=1, 
            freq = FALSE)
  lines(l, lwd = 2)
  size.shape <- 1.3
  n <- 0.1
  pch_vector <- c(15, 7, 6, 16, 17)
  # plot the first five tests for starters
  for (current_test_index in 1:5) {
    test_name <- df_columns[5 + current_test_index]
    test_vector <- df_current_color[df_current_color[test_name] == 1, current_component]
    for (x in test_vector)  {
      if (current_test_index == 1)  {
        points(x, l$y[max(which(x > l$x))] + 0,
               cex = size.shape, pch = pch_vector[current_test_index])
      } else {
        points(x, l$y[max(which(x > l$x))] - par("yaxp")[2] * (current_test_index - 1) * n,
               cex = size.shape, pch = pch_vector[current_test_index])
      }
    }
  }
}

dev.off()
```

And since I cannot upload the csv files.  here is a snapshot of both main.csv and lookup.csv

```
core_depth,hra,pc1,pc2,rhob,MRP ,XRD ,Geochem ,GC ,OP ,SSK ,BET ,TS,SEM ,NMR ,TXC ,BZT ,FT ,PE,CST ,MICP,OR,RW,TPGP,TGA ,DS,KF,CST,CO,FA
8305.03,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999
8305.06281,Green3,1.311306,-2.641727,2.62,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999
8305.09562,Green3,1.310027,-2.57709,2.62,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999
8305.12843,Green3,1.299473,-2.526686,2.61,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999
8305.16123,Green3,1.250434,-2.562131,2.64,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999
8305.19404,Green3,1.308886,-2.505513,2.634925,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999
8305.22685,Green3,1.285146,-2.477449,2.63,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999
8305.25966,Green3,1.202284,-2.5237,2.64,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999
8305.29247,Green3,1.142869,-2.566874,2.64,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999
8305.32528,Green3,1.138197,-2.601127,2.64,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999
8305.35808,Green3,1.13805,-2.626172,2.66,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999
8305.39089,Green3,1.19202,-2.600554,2.66,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999
8305.4237,Green3,1.202864,-2.626277,2.66,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999
8305.45651,Green3,1.109449,-2.658444,2.66,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999
8305.48932,Green3,1.069722,-2.663563,2.66,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999
8305.52213,Green3,1.043733,-2.65977,2.66,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999
8305.55493,Green3,1.020991,-2.636292,2.66,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999
8305.58774,Green3,0.975608,-2.646655,2.67,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999
8305.62055,Green3,0.876026,-2.692267,2.67,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999
8305.65336,Green3,0.850114,-2.696088,2.67,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999
```

And here is the lookup.csv file:

```
hra,red,green,blue
Purple0,128,0,128
Purple1,165,0,165
Purple2,191,0,191
Black0,0,0,0
Black1,34,34,34
Black2,58,58,58
Black3,81,81,81
Black4,104,104,104
Black5,128,128,128
Black6,151,151,151
Black7,174,174,174
Black8,197,197,197
Black9,221,221,221
Brown0,128,0,0
Brown1,141,41,5
Brown2,154,82,11
Brown3,173,115,58
Brown4,192,148,104
Olive0,128,128,0
Olive1,144,144,34
Olive2,156,156,58
Olive3,168,168,81
Olive4,179,179,104
Olive5,191,191,128
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a proper [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data so we could run the code and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Exactly the place that we need to see - the plots inside the for loop - are what you left out with ...

Comment: I am quite willing to post my script.  it is not too long.  I was just trying to be clear.  I can also post scaled down data files if that helps.  Please let me know how.  It seems like I cannot edit the original post anymore.